# Trying to connect to a wifi network with a list of simple passwords with python

Tags: python, linux, wifi, penetration-testing, iwconfig

I have writen a script in python to attempt to connect to a defined wifi network with a list of simple passwords.

```
import wifimangement_linux as wifi              
import os

wifiname = input("Enter Wifi SSID: ")

print("Wifi not stored, testing password...")
file = open('/home/asive/Documents/seclists/wordlists/passwords.lst', 'r')
line = file.readlines()
for i in line:
    try:
        print("Testing Key " + i.strip())
        stream = os.popen("iwconfig wlan0 essid " +  wifiname() + " key s:" + i.strip())
    except:
        print (i.strip() + " failed, trying next.")
    else:
        print ("Success Key==" + i.strip())
```

The script only runs through the program seemingly without trying to connect.

i've tried using subprocess instead of os and running in root, including adding sudo to the bash command.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: are you receiving any errors? if you do, add it to the question, please

Comment: Don't just catch all exceptions and print a simple error message "... failed...". You are losing important information about the error. Calling `traceback.print_exc()` in the except-block at least prints the full traceback. Hint: There is an error in your code.